# MongoDB Object data type won't save with defined schema

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor, schema

Using Mongo and Meteor with CoffeeScript, I'm trying to save a document with one Object:

```
Test = new SimpleSchema(
  tag:
    type: Object
)
```

And the insert:

```
test1 = new Meteor.Collection("test", { schema: Test})
test1.insert({ tag: {"name": "campus"} })
```

*Result: a document gets saved in the database but the "tag" field is never set.*

Couple of different troubleshooting steps I've taken:

1. Changing the data type to String works and the "tag" field gets set.  However, I want to reference a tag property without having to parse the string every time.
2. Adding a collection without the schema saves the Object exactly how I want:

   ```
   test2 = new Meteor.Collection("test2")
   test2.insert({ tag: {"name": "campus"} })
   ```

---

**EDIT: Fixed using the blackbox: true flag.  See below answer for clarification.**

```
Test = new SimpleSchema(
  tag:
    type: Object
    blackbox: true
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to SimpleSchema docs, all defined properties must pass validation.  So any Object data type without properties is treated as an empty Object unless you add the blackbox: true flag.

Source: http://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema#blackbox

If you have a key with type Object, the properties of the object will be validated as well, so you must define all allowed properties in the schema. If this is not possible or you don't care to validate the object's properties, use the blackbox: true option to skip validation for everything within the object.

Answer (score 0):

I use simple schema and create my models of the following way, and I don't have any problem.

```
    Test = new Meteor.Collection("test", {
        schema: new SimpleSchema({
            ownerId: {
                type: String,
            },
            dateAdd: {
                type: Date,
            }
        })
    })

   Test.insert({ownerId:"123",dateAdd:"..."})
```

In Coffee Script

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection("test",
  schema: new SimpleSchema(
    ownerId:
      type: String

    dateAdd:
      type: Date
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I'm having is just with the Object data type.  Dates and Strings will save just fine.